# Angular 4 could not authenticate with IdentityServer4

Tags: angular, identityserver4

Trying to authenticate user with `IdentityServer4` with `ResourceOwnerPassword` grant type.

My application look very similar to [Angular SPA Web API - Explanation](https://github.com/robisim74/AngularSPAWebAPI/blob/master/EXPLANATION.md). The issue is - whenever I making a `POST` request to `http://localhost:49950/connect/token` to request token I get an `400 Bad Request` as a result.

In IdentityServer4 logs I see:

Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:49950/connect/token application/x-www-form-urlencode 166
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:49950/connect/token application/x-www-form-urlencode 166

...

...

CORS request made for path: /connect/token from origin: http://localhost:5000

...

Client list checked and origin: http://localhost:5000 is allowed

...

CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:5000

...

Request path /connect/token matched to endpoint type Token

...

Mapping found for endpoint: Token, creating handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint

...

Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token

...

**Invalid HTTP request for token endpoint**

IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint:Warning: Invalid HTTP request for token endpoint
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-07-27T09:05:22.8471704Z","tags":{"ai.operation.id":"0HL6KPQE44JVG","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"XE0806001077","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.0.0","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.operation.name":"POST /connect/token","ai.internal.nodeName":"XE0806001077","ai.location.ip":"::1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.TokenErrorResult","severityLevel":"Verbose","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","{OriginalFormat}":"Invoking result: {type}","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","CategoryName":"IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware","type":"IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.TokenErrorResult"}}}}

What does it mean **Invalid HTTP request for token endpoint** ?

This is a POST request:

```
POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:49950
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 166
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Basic YWxleDp0ZXN0UGFzc3dvcmQ=
Origin: http://localhost:5000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencode
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer: http://localhost:5000/dashboard
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4
```

What should I change on Angular side or IdentityServer4 on ASP Core to allow the token request ?
Note: It's correctly work from Postman with the same user details in request `body` - the same thing I'm doing in Angular but get `Invalid HTTP request for token endpoint` :(

Comment: Hi Jasper your question is still open. I guess you could add an answer saying the solution (You must to sent application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead application/x-www-form-urlencode also passing the grant-type). It's just a suggestion because I think you already has the solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's no body to the request you've shown. Is one being sent?

A ROPC request should look something like the below:

```
 POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:49950
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w
```

Where the `Authorization` header is your client credentials (client id & secret), not the users username & password

Comment: yes yes I send the parameters in request. Sorry for misleading question - it seems to work now. The problem was in typo in `Content-Type`. I send `application/x-www-form-urlencode` instead `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` <- note the encode**d**

Comment: This is a very strange - now application complain that:
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      Grant type is missing

How it could be ?? I'm sending everything in `body` of request